# Base table or view not found error

Tags: database, sql, php-7

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   tradesbarn_cmestore.core_website doesn't exist

**Query was:**

`SELECT core_website.website_id, core_website.code, core_website.name FROM core_website`

Comment: Add more description, how this error is display? And from where? And which magento version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check your database and check  `core_website` table is there or not.

If not then there is a installation issue. You have to install magento again.